# Ignite visor command is erroring with ClusterGroupEmptyCheckedException: Cluster group is empty

Tags: cluster-computing, ignite

I have a datanode and server node in my cluster.

1. I am trying to connect to the running nodes using the ignitevisor command. 
   one
2. I hit `open` with the `default-config.xml` on the ignitevisor cmd.
3. I then issue the 'cache' command to view the caches and i get an error: o

   ```
   [WARN ] Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive.
   [WARN ] Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster.
   [WARN ] To activate the cluster execute following command: top -activate.
   ```
4. Based on this above message I issue the top --activate command and i get the below error:

   ```
   visor> cache
   [WARN ] Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive.
   [WARN ] Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster.
   [WARN ] To activate the cluster execute following command: top -activate.
   visor> top -activate
   class org.apache.ignite.cluster.ClusterGroupEmptyException: Cluster group is empty.
   ```

NOTE: I tried to activate the cluster using control.sh as well. using
`control.sh --activate`  command below is the output saying it activated the cluster successfully.

However if i try to reopen the ignitevisor cmd the `cache` command on it again errors out with the same logs

```
visor> cache
[WARN ] Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive.
[WARN ] Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster.
[WARN ] To activate the cluster execute following command: top -activate.
```

Please suggest my any fix, or any configuration that i might be missing.to make the ignitevisor command work i am using ignite 2.6.0

Comment: I think you might get hit by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8774. Please try to remove work directory of all nodes, activate cluster before connecting with Visor.

Comment: Make sure you're connecting to the same cluster you're activating. In your case it would mean that the cluster itself should also use the `default-config.xml`.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov how do i ensure that the cluster is using the `default-config.xml` ? Since i am just trying to start the cluster using control.sh --activate command . <br> also i am running the `data-node` and the `service-node` using thier individual xmls, hence for running ignitevisor should i use the `data-node xml` if so, then, wont `ignite` endup starting one more `data-node ` alltogather?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the same config. No, Visor will not start a data node, i.e. it will not create caches, store data, server requests, etc. The config is needed primarily for the network settings.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov i tried using the same config as the one used to start the `data-node` xml. the cluster-state if i check also says that it is active. `$ ./control.sh --state
Control utility [ver. 2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc]
2018 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
User: appusr
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cluster is active
` However if I run the ignitevisor command post that it again keeps saying that the cluster is not active.

Comment: Has to be something with connectivity I think. Please share logs from all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check that server that you run have the same version as visor

2) Try to modify the default config from $IGNITE_HOME/config/default-config.xml as next:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <!-- Setting up IP finder for this cluster -->
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                //change it
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47510</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

instead of default:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"/>
</beans>
```